# I want to make multi Class SVM using Dynamic time warping kernel

Tags: c#, machine-learning, svm, accord.net

I am using accord.net. Following example is working fine, but i want to make Multi class classifier.
I tried using MulticlassSupportVectorMachine() Function but it  trained the data with 0.6 error for Dynamic time warping class kernel, which was not giving right output for certain input.

```
    // Suppose you have sequences of multivariate observations, and that
// those sequences could be of arbitrary length. On the other hand, 
// each observation have a fixed, delimited number of dimensions.

// In this example, we have sequences of 3-dimensional observations. 
// Each sequence can have an arbitrary length, but each observation
// will always have length 3:   
 double[][][] sequences ={
  new double[][] // first sequence
{
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, // first observation of the first sequence
    new double[] { 1, 2, 1 }, // second observation of the first sequence
    new double[] { 1, 4, 2 }, // third observation of the first sequence
    new double[] { 2, 2, 2 }, // fourth observation of the first sequence
},

new double[][] // second sequence (note that this sequence has a different length)
{
    new double[] { 1, 1, 1 }, // first observation of the second sequence
    new double[] { 1, 5, 6 }, // second observation of the second sequence
    new double[] { 2, 7, 1 }, // third observation of the second sequence
},

new double[][] // third sequence 
{
    new double[] { 8, 2, 1 }, // first observation of the third sequence
},

new double[][] // fourth sequence 
{
    new double[] { 8, 2, 5 }, // first observation of the fourth sequence
    new double[] { 1, 5, 4 }, // second observation of the fourth sequence
}
};
// Now, we will also have different class labels associated which each 
// sequence. We will assign -1 to sequences whose observations start 
// with { 1, 1, 1 } and +1 to those that do not:

int[] outputs =
{
  -1,-1,  // First two sequences are of class -1 (those start with {1,1,1})
    1, 1,  // Last two sequences are of class +1  (don't start with {1,1,1})
};

// At this point, we will have to "flat" out the input sequences from             double[][][]
    // to a double[][] so they can be properly understood by the SVMs. The      problem is 
// that, normally, SVMs usually expect the data to be comprised of fixed-length 
// input vectors and associated class labels. But in this case, we will be feeding
// them arbitrary-length sequences of input vectors and class labels associated with
// each sequence, instead of each vector.

double[][] inputs = new double[sequences.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < sequences.Length; i++)
inputs[i] = Matrix.Concatenate(sequences[i]);


// Now we have to setup the Dynamic Time Warping kernel. We will have to
// inform the length of the fixed-length observations contained in each
// arbitrary-length sequence:
// 
DynamicTimeWarping kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(length: 3);

// Now we can create the machine. When using variable-length
/    / kernels, we will need to pass zero as the input length:
var svm = new KernelSupportVectorMachine(kernel, inputs: 0);


// Create the Sequential Minimal Optimization learning algorithm
var smo = new SequentialMinimalOptimization(svm, inputs, outputs)
{
Complexity = 1.5
};

// And start learning it!
double error = smo.Run(); // error will be 0.0


// At this point, we should have obtained an useful machine. Let's
// see if it can understand a few examples it hasn't seem before:

double[][] a = 
{ 
new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
new double[] { 7, 2, 5 },
new double[] { 2, 5, 1 },
};

double[][] b =
{
new double[] { 7, 5, 2 },
new double[] { 4, 2, 5 },
new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
};

// Following the aforementioned logic, sequence (a) should be
// classified as -1, and sequence (b) should be classified as +1.

int resultA = System.Math.Sign(svm.Compute(Matrix.Concatenate(a))); // -1
int resultB = System.Math.Sign(svm.Compute(Matrix.Concatenate(b))); // +1
```

I need help to implement Multi class SVM classifier using MulticlassSupportVectorMachine() , which trains the machine for the input of more than two types and have output labels for each type of input. 
P.S: If  MulticlassSupportVectorMachine() function does not support Dynamic time warping kernel. Than   please tell me how to use one vs one Multiclass svm technique in above Dynamic Time warping kernel, and make multi classifier using one vs one technique.
Your help will be appreciated very much.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
var smo = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
            {
                // Set the parameters of the kernel
                Kernel = new DynamicTimeWarping(alpha: 1, degree: 1)
            };
            // And use it to learn a machine!
            var svm = smo.Learn(words, labels);
            // Create the multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
            var calibration = new MulticlassSupportVectorLearning<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
            {
                Model = svm, // We will start with an existing machine

                // Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
                //  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
                Learner = (param) => new ProbabilisticOutputCalibration<DynamicTimeWarping, double[][]>()
                {
                    Model = param.Model // Start with an existing machine
                }
            };
            // Configure parallel execution options
            calibration.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
            // Learn a machine
            calibration.Learn(words, labels);
            // Obtain class predictions for each sample
            int[] predicted = svm.Decide(words);
            int[] expected = new int[words.Length];


            double correct = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                expected[i] = labels[i];
                predicted[i] = svm.Decide(words[i]);
                if (svm.Decide(words[i]) == labels[i])
                {
                    correct++;
                }

            }
            string Accurecy = "SMO Accurecy = " + (correct / predicted.Length).ToString() + Environment.NewLine; // ori
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for helping out with an answer, but if would be even more helpful if you added some explanation to your code.